# Which one the most efficient - HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

In hibernate, for example I have two object which has relation. The object is like this

First object : Customer

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer", catalog = "test")
public class Customer implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Set<CustomerController> customerControllers = new HashSet<CustomerController>(0);
    public Customer() {
    }
    //getter & setter
}
```

Second Object : CustomerController

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_controller", catalog = "test")
public class CustomerController implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Integer id;
    private Customer customer;
    //constructor, getter & setter
}
```

I want to select the customer_controller of certain customer. I get it by two manner. First manner :

```
@Override
public List<CustomerController> customerController(int customerId){
    Customer customer = (Customer) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Customer.class, customerId);
    return customer.getCustomerControllers()
}
```

Second manner :

```
 return (List<CustomerController>)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("SELECT O FROM CustomerController O WHERE O.customerId=:CONDITION")
.setParameter("CONDITION", customerId)
.list();
```

Which manner is the most efficient one? Why?
Thank you.

Comment: Default loading for `Many` side is `Lazy` so both will have same performance if you do not specify `Eager` fetch which should be only specified if `Many` side has less results or you will face performance bottleneck on `One` side

Comment: Profile it. But I think the second is faster because the first query will use two server round trips (if loaded lazy) whereas the second only uses one server round trip.

Comment: in case it lazy load, I agree with you. But do you have any reference to say it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure it is easier to "turn on" show SQL parameter and monitor it.

I suppose in **first** hibernate able to generate two SQL query with entity mapping.
In **second** case should be generated only one *select* query.

In case when we use FetchType.EAGER think Hibernate will map *Customer* and *CustomerController* entity. Hope Hibernate fetch only *CustomerController* using HQL. To ensure you should monitor Hibernate behavior.

Comment: in case it lazy load, I agree with you. But do you have any reference to say it?

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazy first paragraph